# Undefined symbol: _swift_getOpaqueTypeConformance - React Native & SwiftUI

Tags: objective-c, react-native, swiftui

I'm trying to port a SwiftUI view into react native following this [guide](https://medium.com/better-programming/react-native-meets-swiftui-d1606a8e1681). It build fine in swift project but not in a react native project.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_swift_getOpaqueTypeConformance", referenced from:
      lava.ColorWheelView.body.getter : some in ColorWheelView.o
      closure #2 (SwiftUI.GeometryProxy) -> <<opaque return type of lava.ColorWheelView.makeView(SwiftUI.GeometryProxy) -> some>>.0 in lava.ColorWheelView.body.getter : some in ColorWheelView.o
      associated type witness table accessor for SwiftUI.View.Body : SwiftUI.View in lava.ColorWheelView : SwiftUI.View in lava in ColorWheelView.o
      l_get_witness_table qd0__7SwiftUI4ViewHD3_AaBPAAE7gesture_9includingQrqd___AA11GestureMaskVtAA0F0Rd__lFQOyAA15ModifiedContentVyAA6ZStackVyAA05TupleC0VyAJyAA06_ShapeC0VyAA9RectangleVAA5ColorVGAA12_FrameLayoutVG_AJy4lava010GuitarPickC0VAA13_OffsetEffectVGtGGAA09_PositionP0VG_AA06_EndedF0VyAA0f5StateF0VyAA08_ChangedF0VyAA04DragF0VGSo7CGPointVSgGGQo_HO in ColorWheelView.o
      associated type witness table accessor for SwiftUI.View.Body : SwiftUI.View in lava.TrianglePath : SwiftUI.View in lava in GuitarPickView.o
      associated type witness table accessor for SwiftUI.View.Body : SwiftUI.View in lava.GuitarPickView : SwiftUI.View in lava in GuitarPickView.o
  "_swift_getTypeByMangledNameInContextInMetadataState", referenced from:
      ___swift_instantiateConcreteTypeFromMangledNameAbstract in ColorWheelView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

To reproduce I made this [Github repo](https://github.com/ryansaam/stack-overflow-question-1)

Copy those files in a react native project and try to build. Make sure to replace the header file import with your test project name `"<Replace This>-Swift.h"`

My build target is iOS 13.5 iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator.

Comment: this pretty much points to something in this `var body:` [line:90](https://github.com/ryansaam/stack-overflow-question-1/blob/ebd46cc4355e00abdca5c7c47d32623ac953de85/ColorWheelView.swift#L90) more specific [line:98](https://github.com/ryansaam/stack-overflow-question-1/blob/ebd46cc4355e00abdca5c7c47d32623ac953de85/ColorWheelView.swift#L98)

Comment: 2nd closure going to iterate async and seems to return null. did you place logging in there to see whats going on?

Comment: @OlSen I didn't do logging because I didn't think I needed to debug since this works fine in a regular Swift build without React Native. And `var body: some view`  is just standard code required by the `View` protocol.

Comment: opaque type non-conformance for var body (of TrianglePath, GuitarPickView, ColorWheelView and GeometryProxy *which is an NSObject and not a view*).

Comment: the medium guide is actually wrong with assumtion the proxy can only be NSObject because of swift exposure.. instead the exposed object must inherit from NSObject, what UIView clearly already does. So i still think it should be `@objc class SwiftUIColorWheelProxy : UIView {}`. UIView is an NSObject.

Comment: I had the same issue. Have a look at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30234 I finally managed to build.

Comment: https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-ios/issues/305